# Faster way to transform text vector to numeric matrix/data.frame in R?

Tags: r

I'm using R to parse out some server logs that produce lists that look like this:

```
myLog <- c("[1,2,3]","[4,5,6]","[7,8,9]")
```

What I want to produce from them is a matrix that looks like this:

```
myMatrix <- matrix(c(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9)),nrow=3,byrow=T)
```

They come from querying a database field of type varchar so I don't think I can use any file-reading tricks.

I tend to have lots of these, millions of rows at a time.

What I've been doing is the following, it's quite slow:

```
splitDat <- sapply(inputVector,function(y){
  y1 <- gsub("\\[","",y)
  y2 <- gsub("\\]","",y1)
  y3 <- strsplit(y2,split=", ")
  y4 <- unlist(y3)
})
```

Is there a more efficient way? A one-liner regex?

Comment: Does the following makes it any better `matrix(as.numeric(unlist(sapply(myLog, function(x) strsplit(gsub("\\]|\\[", "", x), ",")))),nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to vectorize this using the `stringi` package

```
library(stringi)
matrix(as.numeric(unlist(stri_extract_all_regex(myLog, pattern = "\\d"))), 
                  nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    4    5    6
# [3,]    7    8    9
```

---

**Benchmarks**

```
library(stringi)
library(gsubfn)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(123)
myLog <- c("[1,2,3]","[4,5,6]","[7,8,9]")
myLog <- sample(myLog, 1e4, replace = TRUE)

Res <- microbenchmark(
               David = matrix(as.numeric(unlist(stri_extract_all_regex(myLog, pattern = "\\d"))), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE),
               Thela = matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(myLog,"\\[|\\]|,"))),nrow=length(myLog),byrow=TRUE)[,-1],
               BD1 =  matrix(as.numeric(scan(text=gsub("\\D"," ",myLog),what="")), nrow=length(myLog),byrow=T),
               BD2 = matrix(as.numeric(scan(text=gsub("[],[]"," ",myLog), what="")),nrow=length(myLog), byrow=T),
               GG1 = read.table(text = gsub("\\D", " ", myLog)),
               GG2 = read.pattern(text = myLog, pat = "\\d")
)

Res
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
# David  12.01351  12.90111  16.41127  13.98826  15.62786 101.65117   100
# Thela  25.49944  27.09937  29.83234  28.32153  30.24141  80.79836   100
#   BD1  92.39541  94.81445 101.20524  98.07333 102.41877 172.60835   100
#   BD2  91.91578  94.66958 104.02773  96.94019 103.99383 206.37865   100
#   GG1  91.28813  94.29219  98.63825  96.57544 100.57172 140.97998   100
#   GG2 470.43382 514.58552 551.94922 540.86479 570.88711 815.75789   100

boxplot(Res)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the `stringi` package!  I'll definitely be using *that* in the future!

Comment: Yes `stringi` is definitely the best regex package in the market. Both by speed and by variety of functions

Comment: The fastest solution it seems as per my benchmarking

Comment: I didn't specify my exact case, so it's worth noting I'm searching for +/-floats, so I use the regex `-?\\d?\\.\\d+`.

16 million rows saw a 17.4x speedup!

Answer (score 6):

**1)** I haven't checked how fast this is but the code is very short:

```
library(gsubfn)
read.pattern(text = myLog, pat = "\\d")
```

where `myLog` is as in the question.

**2)** Here is a base solution:

```
read.table(text = gsub("\\D", " ", myLog))
```

Comment: This function is very nice, though it seems that you need to add `as.matrix` here (if I understand the question correctly)

Comment: While short, the run time seems long on a big vector and it has actually now killed my R session.

Comment: Have added a base solution.

Comment: @David, The subject says matrix/data.frame.

Answer (score 4):

This seems pretty quick (~2 secs on a million cases), though not as quick as the `stringi` solution by David:

```
matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(myLog,"\\[|\\]|,"))),nrow=length(myLog),
       byrow=TRUE)[,-1]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    4    5    6
#[3,]    7    8    9
```

Benchmarking on 30K cases (All but the first two actually caused my R session to become non-responsive when testing on 1 million cases):

```
myLog <- c("[1,2,3]","[4,5,6]","[7,8,9]")
myLog <- sample(myLog, 30000,replace=TRUE)
```

Fastest two:

```
library(stringi)
system.time(
matrix(as.numeric(unlist(stri_extract_all_regex(myLog, pattern = "\\d"))), 
                  nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
)

#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.03    0.00    0.03 

system.time(
matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(myLog,"\\[|\\]|,"))),nrow=length(myLog),
       byrow=TRUE)[,-1]
)

#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.05    0.00    0.04
```

Middling:

```
system.time(
matrix(as.numeric(scan(text=gsub("\\D"," ",myLog),what="")),
       nrow=length(myLog),byrow=T)
)

#Read 90000 items
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.57    0.00    0.58 

system.time(
matrix(as.numeric(scan(text=gsub("[],[]"," ",myLog), what="")),
       nrow=length(myLog), byrow=T)
)

#Read 90000 items
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.59    0.00    0.59 

system.time(
read.table(text = gsub("\\D", " ", myLog))
)

#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.59    0.00    0.60
```

Slower:

```
library(gsubfn)
system.time(
read.pattern(text = myLog, pat = "\\d")
)

#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.79    0.00    1.79
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 myMatrix <- matrix(as.numeric(scan(text=gsub("[],[]"," ",myLog), 
                                    what="")), 
                    nrow=length(myLog), byrow=T)
#Read 9 items
myMatrix

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

Seeing G_G's pattern made me realize the negation of digit could be used in the gsub call:

```
> myMatrix <- matrix(as.numeric(scan(text=gsub("\\D"," ",myLog),what="")),nrow=length(myLog),byrow=T)
```